# Rename the extension of huge number of files Bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I want to change extension of large number of files,

Example: **"ABC.dat.length.doc.fasta"**

Desired: **ABC.mat**

Answer (score 5):

You can use `bash` parameter expansion in a `for` loop:

```
for file in *.length.doc.fasta
do
  mv "$file" "${file%dat.length.doc.fasta}"mat
done
```

Another way to do it:

```
for file in *.length.doc.fasta
do
  mv "$file" "${file%%.*}".mat
done
```

Comment: Can you explain why there is no `.mat` anywhere in your answer?

Comment: Of course, but I assumed a typo in the question, see my comment

Comment: Since only the first component of the file name is kept, `${file%%.*}` is a simpler way to strip the remaining parts.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to using `bash` or `awk` it is possible to use the rarely used command line tool `rename`:

```
rename .dat.length.doc.fasta .mat *.dat.length.doc.fasta
```

This replaces the first argument with the second argument for the files provided is subsequent arguments (here represented by the shell expansion of `*.dat.length.doc.fasta`).

Answer (score 1):

**prename** will do this easily for you. Uses regular expressions to locate and rename files.

```
prename 's/(.*)\.dat\.length\.doc\.fasta/$1.mat/' *.dat.length.doc.fasta
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single line using AWK:

```
ls -1 *.dat.length.doc.fasta | awk -F"." '{system("mv "$0" "$1".mat")}' -
```

Input:

```
$ ls
ABC.dat.length.doc.fasta
ABCD.dat.length.doc.fasta
ABCDE.dat.length.doc.fasta
do_not_touch.txt
```

Output:

```
$ ls
ABCDE.mat
ABCD.mat
ABC.mat
do_not_touch.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 *.dat.length.doc.fasta | nawk '{p=$0;gsub("dat.length.doc.fasta","mat");system("mv "p" "$0); }'
```